# Drawing the perimeter of a rectangle with white space in the middle

Tags: java, netbeans

I have to draw a perimeter of a rectangle using specifications entered by the user- it's supposed to look like this

```
**********
*        *
*        *
*        *
**********
```

by mines has all the center full- how do I get the center to be white space?

this is my code so far

***SOURCE CODE***
     package lab5;
     import java.util.Scanner;

```
 public class Lab5 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);

    int i, j, width, height;
    String x;

    System.out.print("Enter a character: ");
    x = inputReader.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter a height: ");
    height = inputReader.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter a width: ");
    width = inputReader.nextInt();

    for(i = 1; i <=height; i++) {
        for(j = 1; j <= width; j++) {
            System.out.print(x);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you describe in words how you need to print out each line?

Comment: I need it to look like this  3width * 3 height but just to print out the perimeter not the center

Comment: Perhaps I should restate my suggestion: Describe in words what characters you must print out in a single line of the rectangle. Often using English, or your native language, to describe a problem will help you see how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compacted an if/else statement into your for loop. Prints char if top border, bottom border, left column, or right column.

```
for(i = 1; i <=height; i++) {
    for(j = 1; j <= width; j++) {
        if(i == 1 || i == height || j == 1 || j == width)
            System.out.print(x);
        else
            System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

uh... print whitespace.

```
System.out.print(x);
for(j = 2; j <= width-1; j++) {
    System.out.print(" ");
}
System.out.print(x);
```

Comment: I have that in my code as you can see, my issue is how do I make it so it only prints out the outline of the shape (perimeter) not the full center?

Comment: @user3681591 you have what in your code?  `System.out.print(" ");`?  I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Okay, I apologize, my question how do I control how many spaces prints out and where do I place it?

Comment: @user3681591 you do it the same way that you control how many `x`s it prints

Answer (score 1):

The other solution won't work as we cannot do to

```
height = inputReader.nextInt();
width = inputReader.nextInt();
```

it won't take the correct input for the width.

The correct implementation is : **(Note the code is tried and complied)**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i, j, width, height;
    String x;
    System.out.print("Enter a character: ");
    x = inputReader.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter a height: ");
    height = Integer.parseInt(inputReader.nextLine());
    System.out.print("Enter a width: ");
    width = Integer.parseInt(inputReader.nextLine());

    for(i = 0; i <= height; i++) {
        System.out.print(x);
        for(j = 1; j <= width-1; j++) {
            if(i==0 || i==height) {
                System.out.print(x);
                continue;
            }
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print(x);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print spaces using System.out.print(" ") when i and j are not at the boundaries.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrintBox {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);

        int i, j, width, height;
        String x;

        System.out.print("Enter a character: ");
        x = inputReader.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter a height: ");
        height = inputReader.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter a width: ");
        width = inputReader.nextInt();

        for(i = 1; i <= height; i++) {
            for(j = 1; j <= width; j++) {
                if (i == 1 || i == height || j == 1 || j == width)
                    System.out.print(x);
                else
                    System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<width;i++){
    System.out.println(x);
}
for(int i=0;i<height;i++){
    System.out.println(x);
    for(int j=0;j<width-2;j++){
       System.out.println(" ");
    }
    System.out.println(x);
}
for(int i=0;i<width;i++){
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Comment: This makes an infinant loop for me :/